# Share Custom Extension with ADO Server 2020

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We're using Azure DevOps Server 2020. When I created a custom extension for our release, I want to share it with our org. However, all I see on the ADO UI is this:

[image]

The problem is, our url is not https://dev.azure.com, it's https://devops.mycompany.com...

How can I change this and get it to share to my org?

Answer (score 0):

According to your sharing, the URL which you shared was for Service not for Server, and if you would like to publish a custom extension on Server, please refer to the documents: [Develop a web extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?view=azure-devops) & [Package and publish extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/publish/overview?view=azure-devops) for more information. Besides, for "Create a publisher", you should Sign in to the [Visual Studio Marketplace Publishing Portal](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/manage/createpublisher?managePageRedirect=true) .

And regarding your description, please refer to this step "Select Organization, and then enter the name of your organization. Select Enter." and have a check.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukg7Y.png)

Hope it's helpful to you.

Comment: Not really, no. All of those recourses, which I've read, basically lead to the same place. An option to share with an "organization" where you type in the org name, that cannot be found under our conditions.